# Custom Responsive grid column sizes not sizing properly

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, grid

Ok. Long time reader first time poster. So I have been trying to create a custom grid system so I don't have to rely on frameworks such as `bootstrap` or boilerplate all the time. I have got the grid working but, When a `col-12x` is above another `col-12x`. The first columns still has `15px` of `padding` on the `right`, and some columns don't have the `padding` on the right of the last column in a row. The text wont break the same as it is for identical columns. I have attached a link to a `[JSFIDDLE][1]`  since S.O wont let me put in the `css` for some reason.

```
<div class="grid-fw">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1xs"><p>col-1</p></div>
    <div class="col-1xs"><p>col-1</p></div>
    <div class="col-1xs"><p>col-1</p></div>
    <div class="col-1xs"><p>col-1</p></div>
    <div class="col-1xs"><p>col-1</p></div>
    <div class="col-1xs"><p>col-1</p></div>
    <div class="col-1xs"><p>col-1</p></div>
    <div class="col-1xs"><p>col-1</p></div>
    <div class="col-1xs"><p>col-1</p></div>
    <div class="col-1xs"><p>col-1</p></div>
    <div class="col-1xs"><p>col-1</p></div>
    <div class="col-1xs"><p>col-1</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6xs"><p>col-6</p></div>
    <div class="col-4xs"><p>col-4</p></div>
    <div class="col-2xs"><p>col-2</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6xs col-8lg">
      <div class="col-8xs"><p>col-8</p></div>
      <div class="col-4xs"><p>col-4</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6xs col-4lg"><p>col-8</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4xs"><p>col-4</p></div>
    <div class="col-4xs"><p>col-4</p></div>
    <div class="col-4xs"><p>col-4</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12xs"><p>col-12</p></div>
    <div class="col-12xs"><p>col-12</p></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have a feeling that its the same issue for both things, but its driving me crazy. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not seeing the fiddle link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because `col-12*` it is your max # of columns (like bootstrap), so you can only have one for each `.row` (given your current CSS) where you state:

```css
/* Floats last ".col-" to the right */
[class*='col-']:last-of-type { padding-right: 0; }
```

having two  `col-12*` in one `.row` will make the 1st  `col-12*` to have your default `padding-right:10px` as you state here

```css
/* Column attribute selector */
[class*='col-'] { position: relative; float: left; padding-right: 10px; min-height: 1px; }
```

**Snippet**

```css
/* Grid Container */

.grid,
.grid-fw {
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
/* Phones */

@media (min-width: 420px) {
  .grid {
    width: 400px;
  }
}
/* Mobile */

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .grid {
    width: 750px;
  }
}
/* Tablet */

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .grid {
    width: 970px;
  }
}
/* Desktop  */

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .grid {
    width: 1170px;
  }
}
/* Clearfix */

.row:after,
.row:before {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both !important;
}
/* Column attribute selector */

[class*='col-'] {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 10px;
  min-height: 1px;
}
/* Floats last ".col-" to the right */

[class*='col-']:last-of-type {
  padding-right: 0;
}
/* Phones Grid Columns */

@media only screen and (max-width: 420px) {
  [class*='col-'] {
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
}
/* Grid Columns Mobile First */

@media (min-width: 321px) {
  .col-1xs {
    width: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-2xs {
    width: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-3xs {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-4xs {
    width: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-5xs {
    width: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-6xs {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-7xs {
    width: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-8xs {
    width: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-9xs {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .col-10xs {
    width: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-11xs {
    width: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-12xs {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
/* Tablet Grid Columns Mobile First */

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .col-1sm {
    width: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-2sm {
    width: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-3sm {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-4sm {
    width: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-5sm {
    width: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-6sm {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-7sm {
    width: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-8sm {
    width: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-9sm {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .col-10sm {
    width: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-11sm {
    width: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-12sm {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
/* Laptop Grid Columns */

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .col-1md {
    width: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-2md {
    width: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-3md {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-4md {
    width: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-5md {
    width: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-6md {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-7md {
    width: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-8md {
    width: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-9md {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .col-10md {
    width: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-11md {
    width: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-12md {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
/* Desktop Grid Columns */

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .col-1lg {
    width: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-2lg {
    width: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-3lg {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-4lg {
    width: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-5lg {
    width: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-6lg {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-7lg {
    width: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-8lg {
    width: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-9lg {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .col-10lg {
    width: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-11lg {
    width: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-12lg {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
/* Removes padding behaviour on widths */

*,
*:after,
*:before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* Clearfix for Nested Rows */

.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}
/* Show Columns */

[class*='col-'] > p {
  background-color: #004d81;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-fw">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1xs">
      <p>col-1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1xs">
      <p>col-1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1xs">
      <p>col-1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1xs">
      <p>col-1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1xs">
      <p>col-1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1xs">
      <p>col-1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1xs">
      <p>col-1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1xs">
      <p>col-1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1xs">
      <p>col-1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1xs">
      <p>col-1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1xs">
      <p>col-1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1xs">
      <p>col-1</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6xs">
      <p>col-6</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4xs">
      <p>col-4</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2xs">
      <p>col-2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6xs col-8lg">
      <div class="col-8xs">
        <p>col-8</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4xs">
        <p>col-4</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6xs col-4lg">
      <p>col-8</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4xs">
      <p>col-4</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4xs">
      <p>col-4</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4xs">
      <p>col-4</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12xs">
      <p>col-12</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12xs">
      <p>col-12</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok that makes total sense, thanks. One last thing. I originally thought it had to do with the last-of-type padding. Which works for everything except a row of 12 co-1* on it. On the first row last column you will notice that that column is 10px bigger than the rest.  If i remove the padding from the last of type it seems to fit into shape. I cant really remove that though. So I'm at a loss. :/

Comment: I don't understand your issue

Comment: So if there is a row that has 12 col-1* in it. The last col seems to have 10 extra pixels of padding due to the last-of-type class. But this only seems to happen right before mobile media query. 

      /* Column attribute selector */
      [class*='col-'] { position: relative; float: left; padding-right: 10px; min-height: 1px; } 

If i remove the padding the whole grid breaks of course. But i cant figure out why it is adding the extra padding  but not retaining the same shape as the other columns.

Comment: Its not a major issue i guess. but it urks me. :P

Comment: it doesn't happen in my snippet

Comment: http://www.digitalreligion.net/img/screen.png

Here is a link to a screen shot of what i am talking about.  Thanks again for your help man.

Comment: look at how bootstraps works, and if my answer fixed your main issue, make sure your mark the answer as accepted `:)`